# Plot a discontinuous function in R without connecting a "jump"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot a discontinuous function without connecting a jump. For example, in the following plot, I'd like to delete the line connecting (0.5, 0.5) and (0.5, 1.5).

```
f <- function(x){
  (x < .5) * (x) + (x >= .5) * (x + 1)
}
ggplot()+ 
  geom_function(fun = f)
```

Edit: I'm looking for a solution that works even if the discountinuous point is not a round number, say `pi/10`.

Comment: Since this function is piecewise linear, you could use `geom_segment`.

Comment: Actually a function I have in mind has a discontinuous point depending on parameters and it is nonlinear, so I'm not sure if I can use `geom_segment` or `geom_curve`

Comment: Maybe one can use multiple `geom_function`? One for each continuous piece.

Comment: Typically graphing functions ignore NA values, so maybe you could evaluate your function, put in an NA at the jump, and plot the vector of values rather than getting `geom_function` to do the evaluations.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a little wrapper function which finds discontinuities in the given function and plots them as separate groups:

```r
plot_fun <- function(fun, from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.001) {
  
  x <- seq(from, to, by)
  groups <- cut(x, c(-Inf, x[which(abs(diff(fun(x))) > 0.1)], Inf))
  df <- data.frame(x, groups, y = fun(x))
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = groups)) +
    geom_line()
}
```

This allows

```r
plot_fun(f)
```

[image]

```r
plot_fun(floor, 0, 10)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution if you know how big the discontinuities are.  If you don't know that, but know where they are, there's also a similar solution using groups.

Comment: +1 Nice answer! I'm glad you showed the floor example to emphasize that multiple discontinuities are allowed. I extended your code in a new answer to draw and open and closed points (relying on a new argument "right_continuous").

Answer (score 2):

You can insert everything inside an ifelse:

```
f <- function(x){
  ifelse(x==0.5, 
         NA, 
         (x < .5) * (x) + (x >= .5) * (x + 1))
}
ggplot()+ 
  geom_function(fun = f)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this only works because 0.5 is a round number likely to be chosen by `geom_function`.  If the discontinuity happened at 0.5001 it wouldn't work.

Comment: I agree with the comment by @user2554330. I changed 0.5 to `pi/10`, then it no longer works. In my real application, the discontinuous point is not a round number.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on [Allan Cameron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695962/1376404), but depicts the jump using open and closed circles. Whether the function is right or left continuous is controlled by an argument.

```
library("ggplot2")
plot_fun <- function(fun, from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.001, right_continuous = TRUE) {

  x <- seq(from, to, by)
  tol_vertical <- 0.1
  y <- fun(x)
  idx_break <- which(abs(diff(y)) > tol_vertical)
  x_break <- x[idx_break]
  y_break_l <- y[idx_break]
  y_break_r <- y[idx_break + 1]

  groups <- cut(x, c(-Inf, x_break, Inf))
  df <- data.frame(x, groups, y = fun(x))

  plot_ <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = groups)) +
            geom_line()

  # add open and closed points showing jump
  dataf_l <- data.frame(x = x_break, y = y_break_l)
  dataf_r <- data.frame(x = x_break, y = y_break_r)
  shape_open_circle <- 1
  # this is the default of shape, but might as well specify.
  shape_closed_circle <- 19
  shape_size <- 4
  if (right_continuous) {
    shape_l <- shape_open_circle
    shape_r <- shape_closed_circle
  } else {
    shape_l <- shape_closed_circle
    shape_r <- shape_open_circle
  }

  plot_ <- plot_ +
    geom_point(data = dataf_l, aes(x = x, y = y), group = NA, shape = shape_l, size = shape_size) +
    geom_point(data = dataf_r, aes(x = x, y = y), group = NA, shape = shape_r, size = shape_size)
  return(plot_)
}
```

Here's the OP's original example:

```
f <- function(x){
  (x < .5) * (x) + (x >= .5) * (x + 1)
}
plot_fun(f)
```

[image: Plot of "f"]

Here's Allan's additional example using `floor`, which shows multiple discontinuities:

```
plot_fun(floor, from = 0, to = 10)
```

[image: Plot of "floor"]

And here's an example showing that the function does not need to be piecewise linear:

```
f_curved <- function(x) ifelse(x > 0, yes = 0.5*(2-exp(-x)), no = 0)
plot_fun(f_curved, from = -1, to = 5)
```

[image: Plot of "f_curved"]